# when my users go login.php, users can't continue last page

Tags: php, authentication

when my users go login.php, users can't continue last page.Users redirect index.php.But I want that users can go last page when they logged in.What can I do for it?
Sincerely

Answer (score 1):

Use http_referer as your redirection.

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

Comment: Please give me more information.Because my information is restrict.Where should i use this code?And how can i use this code?

Comment: After you validate that the user logged in, use header($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); And make sure you check that the refere is on your server, and is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the current/last page to the login page through a query parameter, the get the query string and redirect to the parameter.

e.g.

On your non-login page, you'd link to your login page:

`http://mysite.com/login.php?lastPage=/lastpage`

Don't forget to urlencode that lastPage - http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

And the load up the "lastPage" parameter from the REQUEST global

`$strLastPage = $_REQUEST['lastPage'];`

And then redirect to that page in `$strLastPage`

You can learn how to redirect here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-redirect.php

Comment: Also, be sure you check that "lastPage" isn't empty before trying to redirect to it. Might be worth defaulting to either an account page or the home page